# Resize Boot Camp partition

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

I installed Windows 8 on my MacBook Pro using Boot Camp. Now I've figured out I should have made the Windows 8 partition bigger. Is this safe to attempt using Disk Utility? If not, how do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: I *have* used Disk Utility for this in the past, so if you need a free option it is "possible"—but I don't think I'd call it "safe". Definitely have a backup ready and waiting (although you should anyway, and resizing partitions is always somewhat dangerous). Do NOT under any circumstances resize from within Windows, as this WILL kill everything.

Answer (score 2):

Though grgarside's answer was the correct & only correct answer at the time, iPartition is no longer the 'go to' app for this kind of task. It has unfortunately been left to languish & can't handle CoreStorage volumes at all.

The only replacement - & actually improvement - on iPartition is now [**Paragon Hard Disk Manager**](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/)

It can not only resize Bootcamp partitions, it can fix them & even back up or move them to a new drive without breaking anything else in the process.

Full feature list here - https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/features.html

*no affiliation, merely a satisfied user.*

Answer (score 1):

For all my partitioning, I use and recommend [**iPartition**](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iPartition.php).

> You can use iPartition on drives that contain Boot Camp volumes; in fact, you can even resize your Windows partitions, and let iPartition take care of reconfiguring the Windows boot process for you.